# JPA - How to use table default value for primary key generation?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have a table with primary key generation of `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!,'YYDDD')||LPAD(TO_CHAR(SEQ_REFID.NEXTVAL),11,'0'))`

This has been given as default value for the table. When I insert through JDBC, I could leave the column as NULL, so the pk would be generated/defaulted and i'll get the key using `getGeneratedKeys()` method.

I require similar behavior using JPA. I'm a beginner in JPA. Pl help.
Database used is Oracle 11g.

**EDIT:** The above mentioned value is not required to be table default. It can be applied from JPA layer if it is possible.

Other Entities depends on this Entity for the pk. PK must be passed over to all child tables.

Comment: This looks like a very bad database design. Is there a reason why you don't use a simple id-column with increasing integers?

Comment: Expected number of transactions per day would count in millions, prefixing julian date would help extract transactions from history table.

Comment: That's not how you should do this. Make a simple id column with an ascending integer and add an additional column with the current sysdate. This is how it's supposed to be and not only simplifies your queries but also improves the performance. You can also query the table for entries of a specific hour, week and so on, or generate detailed statistics. Don't try to put different data into one cell. There's no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following annotation to the id field:

```
@Column(insertable = false)
```

This way, JPA will ignore the field when inserting new values and the database automatically generates the desired key.

However, you shouldn't use such a primary key. It effectively contains 2 different kinds of data in one column which should better be split into two seperate columns.

Make a simple id column with an ascending integer (and absolutely meaning other than "*this is entry nr. x*"). Then add an additional column with the current timestamp. This timestamp can have a default value and be protected against updates.

This is how it's supposed to be and not only simplifies your queries, but also improves the performance. You can query the table for entries of a specific hour, week and so on, or generate detailed statistics.

Don't try to put multiple information into one column. There's no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

}
```

Can also be

```
GenerationType.AUTO
GenerationType.SEQUENCE
GenerationType.TABLE
```

[This reference describes the various strategies](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that this default PK was a good idea?

If you want the creation time of the row, add a column to your table.  Don't embed it in the PK like this.